# Xml De-Serialisation No Root Node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-deserialization

I have an XML file that I'm receiving form a third party provider.

It's not structured in the conventional way, it basically has no Root :-

```
<DG_X
    attrib1="Test2"
    attrib2="1"
    attrib3="12345">TEST-23456</DG_X>
<DG_Y
    attrib1="test"
    attrib2="Example Text"
    attrib3="1"
    attrib4="3"
    attrib5= 1
    attrib6="12412342134">Test-1234567</DG_Y>
```

I'm only interested in the first Element "DG_X" and i only need its value "TEST-23456".

I'm new to De-Serialistaion, and so far my attempts have failed :-

```
[Serializable]
    [XmlRoot("DG_X")]
    public class DM
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string attrib1 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string attrib2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string attrib3 { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        [XmlElement("DG_Y")]
        public string dg_key { get; set; }

    }
```

The problem lies with reading the second Element, The compiler advises that there are two root elements. What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Comment: You'll have to solve the 'single root' problem before deserialization.  Maybe read it in a XmlReader to the first node and then use that reader to deserialize?

Comment: Is it not possible to read the file without a root?

Comment: Read, yes. Deserialize to a typed object? not that i know of since it's expecting an 'object root' in the xml

Comment: Thanks, I'll try simply reading the file and getting out what i need.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for your example

```
 XmlReader xR = XmlReader.Create(@"example.xml");
            xR.MoveToContent();

            XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DM));
            DM dmInstance = xser.Deserialize(xR) as DM;
```

We're basically using an XmlReader to position ourselfs on the first element and using that to deserialize into the object instance.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get round my problem with the following code:-

This was the only way I could get round having no root node in the file.

```
using (var fileSteam = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment};

                using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileSteam, settings))
                {
                    if (!reader.IsStartElement()) 
                        return String.Empty;

                    var reference = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    return reference.StartsWith("DM-") ? reference : string.Format("DM-{0}", reference);
                }
```